# Pass parameters to WAR file deployed in two instances of JBOSS

Tags: java, jboss

I'm a .NET Programmer and right now I'm struggling with a web service I developed in JAVA. The web service doesn't have access to a database, only do some cryptographic tasks. To deploy it, I build the project with dependencies in Net Beans, generate a WAR File and upload it in the JBOSS web console.

The problem is that I'm looking for the analog of Web.Config in .Net, where some parameters can be set by a human without compiling again . In my code I call a XML file with all the parameters, however, the location of the file must be hardcoded. My solution was to set an enviornment variable with the folder so I always have to look for the XML there.

But I have an inconvenience: The same deploy will be set in two instances of JBOSS in the same server and both web services will have access to the same file, but that can't happen because some configurations are different in each one.

I tried the Web.xml file, but where can I find it in the JBOSS folder? Each time I upload the war or disable/enable it, it change the folder of the web.xml

What can you suggest?

Comment: A Jboss app cannot change its web.xml file, it's always `WEB-INF/web.xml`.  Perhaps you meant something else was changing?

Comment: Maybe I'm too newbie in JBOSS. I'm running JBOSS with the Standalone.bat. Each time I upload the file, the project I got a new folder in jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\tmp\vfs (For example, deployment736eec02607dd911). And there is the web.xml, but if someone edit it, the changes are not refreshed.

Comment: The deployment thing is weird.  You'll have to check whatever tool you are using to upload the file.  For the web.xml file, that should be set/edited in your development environment (just like you edit a source file), then you upload the correct file to the server.  And JBoss would only look at the web.xml file when it starts, if you edit any other time, you have to stop JBoss and restart it to reload the web.xml file (note: its been ages since I've done anything with JBoss, caveat emptor).

Answer (score 0):

The idea of using the web console is to work with artifacts (closed package) and you shouldn´t be manually modifying them.

From what i understood of your requirement, one option is to put an external file in the classpath of each jboss.

https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/HowToPutAnExternalFileInTheClasspath?_sscc=t